# Does "I'm sure a lot of people will resonate with you on that" sound awkward?

Tags: word-usage

**"I'm sure a lot of people will resonate with you on that."**

I am using this in one of my short stories and I am wondering if it is awkward?

Comment: It's "awkward" because that's not how we usually use metaphoric ***resonate***. It's normally abstract nouns like ***ideas, concepts, principles*** that resonate with people (your mind being in some way "fine-tuned" to vibrate in sympathy and absorb certain things). You can't really have that kind of relationship with ***a lot of people*** - it's just that they ***agree*** with you.

Comment: Google Books - ["**it** will resonate with you"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+will+resonate+with+you%22) 461 hits, ["**he** will resonate with you"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+will+resonate+with+you%22) 3 hits.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you don't understand how to use the idiom.

Comment: For "I resonate with you" there are about 121 results on google books?

Comment: Define *awkward*. How awkward? Who's judging, and how?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three standard ways of expressing your idea:

> I'm sure that will resonate with a lot of people.
>
> I'm sure that will ring a bell with a lot of people.
>
> I'm sure a lot of people will be able to relate to that, or I'm sure a lot of people will be able to relate.